# Text in tkinter not in cmd python?

Tags: tkinter

When i run it in CMD tkinter comes up and runs the program but the results/forecast comes up in CMD when i have enter a city, i want to come up in tkinter box program how do i do?

Do i need a label or what?

```
from tkinter import *
    import requests
    import json

    class Application(Frame):

        def __init__(self, master=None):
            Frame.__init__(self, master)
            self.root = master
            self.pack()
            self.create_widgets()

        def create_widgets(self):
            self.v = StringVar()
            self.e = Entry(self, textvariable=self.v)
            self.e.pack(side="left")

            self.v.set("Enter City")
            self.e.focus_set()


            self.butn = Button(self)
            self.butn["text"] = "Forecast"
            self.butn["command"] = self.make_request
            self.butn.pack(side="left")

            self.QUIT = Button(self, text="QUIT", command=self.root.destroy)
            self.QUIT.pack(side="right")


        def make_request(self):
            r = requests.get("http://api.wunderground.com/api/ab78bcbaca641959/forecast/q/Sweden/" + self.v.get() + ".json")
            data = r.json()
            for day in data['forecast']['simpleforecast']['forecastday']:
                print (day['date']['weekday'] + ":")
                print ("Conditions: ", day['conditions'])
                print ("High: ", day['high']['celsius'] + "C", "Low: ", day['low']['celsius'] + "C", '\n')
            return data






    rot = Tk()
    rot.geometry("900x650+200+50")
    rot.title("The Trip")

    app = Application(master=rot)
    app.mainloop()
```

Comment: It is because you are **print** ing the result.Use a `Label` instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you should use labels for data to be displayed on a Tkinter window:
Here is a basic example to do so:

```
from Tkinter import *
root = Tk()
e = Entry(root)
e.pack()
var = StringVar()

def callback():
    var.set(e.get())

e.focus_set()
b = Button(root, text="submit", width=10, command=callback)
b.pack()
label = Label( root, textvariable=var, relief=RAISED)
label.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

This examples will give you idea about how to use StringVar or others to update the label.
Some info [here](http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/label.htm)